# Are the Play Store Alpha/Beta opt-in links the same?

Tags: android, google-play

We're close to launching the open beta for our first game on the play store (Yay!), and we wanted to start giving the link out, but we'd like to print some stuff in advance.

We have a closed alpha, which has an opt-in link. Will this link be the same for the beta, or will it get a new one?

Thanks to anyone can help!

Adam

Answer (score 1):

An opt-in URL is not required for beta testing. Any user can directly search/open the app in play store and join the beta program from there.

If the app is in beta and not published yet, the app will be shown as "Unreleased" and users can directly install without explicitly joining the beta program.

When a user downloads an unreleased app, s/he will automatically become a beta tester.

Comment: @CodeChimp - Thanks! I think your comment more directly answers my question. If you put it as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is still an opt-in URL for beta even though anyone can now join betas. It's the same link as for alpha but alpha is validated against Group or email list. But Nabin is correct, anyone can join a beta now, the link is just a handy way to enroll in the beta.